# What does `y_dim` represent in the following GANs model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

This question is about an implementation example of GANs using TensorFlow on images.

I've excerpted part of code that I thought was enough to provide a context, [reference for full code](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py). In following code, it has defined a discriminator function, which can be considered as a typical convolution neural network, loosely speaking. As it is seen, discriminator operations are conditioned on `y_dim`, **could someone help explain what is `y_dim`**? Looking at `Args`, I am still very confused about the definition of `y_dim`.

```
class DCGAN(object):
    def __init__(self, sess, image_size=108, is_crop=True,
                 batch_size=64, sample_size=64, output_size=64,
                 y_dim=None, z_dim=100, gf_dim=64, df_dim=64,
                 gfc_dim=1024, dfc_dim=1024, c_dim=3, dataset_name='default',
                 checkpoint_dir=None, sample_dir=None):
        """

        Args:
            sess: TensorFlow session
            batch_size: The size of batch. Should be specified before training.
            output_size: (optional) The resolution in pixels of the images. [64]
            y_dim: (optional) Dimension of dim for y. [None]
            z_dim: (optional) Dimension of dim for Z. [100]
            gf_dim: (optional) Dimension of gen filters in first conv layer. [64]
            df_dim: (optional) Dimension of discrim filters in first conv layer. [64]
            gfc_dim: (optional) Dimension of gen units for for fully connected layer. [1024]
            dfc_dim: (optional) Dimension of discrim units for fully connected layer. [1024]
            c_dim: (optional) Dimension of image color. For grayscale input, set to 1. [3]
        """
        ...

    def discriminator(self, image, y=None, reuse=False):
        if reuse:
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

        if not self.y_dim:
            h0 = lrelu(conv2d(image, self.df_dim, name='d_h0_conv'))
            h1 = lrelu(self.d_bn1(conv2d(h0, self.df_dim * 2, name='d_h1_conv')))
            h2 = lrelu(self.d_bn2(conv2d(h1, self.df_dim * 4, name='d_h2_conv')))
            h3 = lrelu(self.d_bn3(conv2d(h2, self.df_dim * 8, name='d_h3_conv')))
            h4 = linear(tf.reshape(h3, [self.batch_size, -1]), 1, 'd_h3_lin')

            return tf.nn.sigmoid(h4), h4
        else:
            yb = tf.reshape(y, [self.batch_size, 1, 1, self.y_dim])
            x = conv_cond_concat(image, yb)

            h0 = lrelu(conv2d(x, self.c_dim + self.y_dim, name='d_h0_conv'))
            h0 = conv_cond_concat(h0, yb)

            h1 = lrelu(self.d_bn1(conv2d(h0, self.df_dim + self.y_dim, name='d_h1_conv')))
            h1 = tf.reshape(h1, [self.batch_size, -1])
            h1 = tf.concat(1, [h1, y])

            h2 = lrelu(self.d_bn2(linear(h1, self.dfc_dim, 'd_h2_lin')))
            h2 = tf.concat(1, [h2, y])

            h3 = linear(h2, 1, 'd_h3_lin')

            return tf.nn.sigmoid(h3), h3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y_dim is the length of the labels.

It seems to be used in the DCGAN class to say 'Do we know the number of training labels'.  If we do we can define all these tensors with the known dimensions.

E.g. Look at the main.py file where the MNIST dataset is used. See that y_dim is set to 10 for the 0-9 labels? It is 'None' for the second option.

Hope this helps.